# How to set custom headers in php unit testcases

Tags: phpunit, custom-headers

How to send token as part of header along with the request in  PHPUnit test cases.I had tried many ways but none of them are not working.

```
1) const TOKEN = 'XXXXXX';
public function testCreateTest()
    {
      $response  = $this->call('POST','/test'.static::TOKEN,['code' => 'sally','sort_order'=>'test'],[],[], ['HTTP_Authorization' => 'token'],[]);
        $this->assertSame(500, $response->getStatusCode());
    }

2)public function testCreateTest()
    {
      $response  = $this->call('POST','/test',[], [], [],$headers = ['token' => static::TOKEN], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = []);
        $this->assertSame(500, $response->getStatusCode());
    }
```

When I tried to print the request the headers are not appended.The output look likes this when I run the testcases.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type:  application/json
Date:          Thu, 13 Oct 2016 07:38:25 GMT
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik4zdTZWbHZyXC8ybFV0MUs4R0UwNUl3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkFWb2cxUmtFdmljbXpxRkpcL2wwUHZyckNobVNrQYyI6IjdkY2FhMTliNjVmMDEwN2ZhNjI3ZjRmNDQxNDZmNmYyMTRkY2E4Yzg1NzY3MGY2OTEwNWY5MDA5ZmJlNDY3MDgifQ%3D%3D; expires=Thu, 13-Oct-2016 09:38:25 GMT; path=/

{"message":"Unauthorized"}
```

Please can anybody help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using some framework? `$this->call(` seems referring to a Laravel funtional test case

Comment: Thanks for reply.I solved this problem.I was trying to send custom header,but it ignores the headers which is not prefix with HTTP_. So we need to prefix custom header as HTTP_